# Why PartialEq bound is needed when comparing associated types

Tags: rust

Here is an example. There is a `Wrapper` struct which is parametrized with a `Trait`, but has a single element of an associated type (`Trait::A`).

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Wrapper<T: Trait>(pub(crate) <T as Trait>::A);

pub trait Trait {
    type A: Eq + PartialEq;

    fn a() -> Self::A;
}

pub fn test<T: Trait>() {
    let wrapper = Wrapper::<T>(T::a());
    let _r = wrapper == wrapper;
}
```

which gives this compiling error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `Wrapper<T>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
12 |     let _r = wrapper == wrapper;
   |              ------- ^^ ------- Wrapper<T>
   |              |
   |              Wrapper<T>
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
10 | pub fn test<T: Trait + std::cmp::PartialEq>() {
   |                      +++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.
```

Why is the `PartialEq` bound required, if no `Trait`s are compared, just `Trait::A`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Wrapper<T: Trait>(pub(crate) <T as Trait>::A);
```

expands to something like

```rust
pub struct Wrapper<T: Trait>(pub(crate) <T as Trait>::A);

impl<T: PartialEq> PartialEq for Wrapper {
   ...
}
```

In `fn test`, you're constructing a `Wrapper<T>`, but `T` is only required to implement `Trait`, not `PartialEq`. The compiler doesn't assume that you really only care if `Trait::A` can be compared.

To tell it, you'll need to implement `PartialEq` manually:

```rust
impl<T: Trait> PartialEq for Wrapper<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0 == other.0
    }
}
```

You may assume that `T: Trait` is implied for every trait impl if `T: Trait` is on the struct definition, but that actually isn't the case.

Comment: I don't see why the compiler has no way of knowing that, but I found [this thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925) which indicates that it's super complicated to support

Comment: @Conrado I run into this a lot, but with stuff like `#[derive(Default)] struct Foo<T> { bar: Option<T> };`. The derive macro includes a bound `T:Default` even though there aren't any `T` fields (`Option<T>` implements `Default` regardless of whether `T` does). It's unfortunate that it requires manual implementations, but at least these derive macros are consistent in that they all add bounds on every type parameter. You get used to it after awhile.